# if $|G|=12$ with no normal subgroups of order $3$ then $|{\rm Syl}_3(G)|=4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group, prove that If $|G|=12$ with no normal subgroups of order $3$ then $|{\rm Syl}_3(G)|=4$

---

From the $3rd$ theorem, we get that $|{\rm Syl}_3(G)|=3p+1, p\in\mathbb{N}$. Also, we know that $|{\rm Syl}_3(G)|$ divides the order of the group, hence  $|{\rm Syl}_3(G)|\in \{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$.

The only $2 $ elements that are in the form $3p+1$ are $1$ and $4$

How can I conclude that $1$ isn't the answer? I don't see how can I use the fact that $G$ has no normal subgroups of order $3$.

I thought maybe I could use the second theorem, but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $|Syl_3(G)|=1$ and let $P$ be the only $3$-Sylow subgroup. Note that for each $g\in G$, the set $gPg^{-1}$ is also a subgroup of size $3$, i.e a $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. But since $P$ is the only $3$-Sylow subgroup, we conclude that we must have $gPg^{-1}=P$ for all $g\in G$. But this exactly means $P\trianglelefteq G$, a contradiction.

In general, a $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal if and only if $|Syl_p(G)|=1$. I showed you how to prove one direction, the second direction follows from the fact that any two $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate. Also, note that if $|G|=p^rm$ where $p$ doesn't divide $m$ then by the third Sylow theorem $|Syl_p(G)|$ divides $m$. (in the question you used that it divides $|G|$, but it even divides $m$)

Comment: I had a felling I had to use the second theorem somehow ! , didn't know how though, thank you.

Comment: The direction you were interested in doesn't require the second Sylow theorem. Note that I only used the fact that $gPg^{-1}$ is also a $3$-Sylow subgroup. But as I said, if you want to show that $|Syl_p(G)|>1$ implies the $p$-Sylow subgroups are not normal (which is the other direction) then you have to use the second Sylow theorem.